# Terraform helm with values

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm, terraform0.12+, helm3

I am using `helm_release` resource on terraform to run Hashicorp vault helm chart.

This is my configuration:

```
resource "helm_release" "vault" {
  name       = "vault"
  repository = "https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com"
  chart      = "vault"
  namespace  = "vault"
  version    = "0.17.1"

  values = [
    data.utils_deep_merge_yaml.values[0].output
  ]
}

data "utils_deep_merge_yaml" "values" {
  input = compact([
    local.values,
    var.values
  ])
}
```

I am trying to inject some yaml config using local values:

```
locals{
  values  = <<EOF
injector:
  enabled: false
global:
  enabled: true
server:
  tolerations:
    - key: "taint_for_vault"
      operator: "Equal"
      value: true
      effect: "NoExecute"
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
             vault_in_k8s: true
          topologyKey: "vault_in_k8s"
  EOF
}
```

I get the following error:

```
StatefulSet in version "v1" cannot be handled as a StatefulSet: v1.StatefulSet.Spec: v1.StatefulSetSpec.Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec.Spec: v1.PodSpec.Tolerations: []v1.Toleration: v1.Toleration.Value: ReadString: expects " or n, but found t, error found in #10 byte of ...|,"value":true}],"vol|..., bigger context ...|ey":"taint_for_vault","operator":"Equal","value":true}],"volumes":[{"configMap":{"name":"vault-confi|...
│   12: resource "helm_release" "vault" {
```

Comment: From the perspective of the Helm chart for Vault and the Terraform config, this looks fine. Please share an example of the `var.values` (presumably more input values for the Vault Helm chart) and/or its Terraform declaration. Also consider outsourcing the `local.values` to a YAML file and reading in with the `file` function, or constructing it in HCL2 and transform it to YAML with `yamlencode`. Those would probably both be much easier for you since this appears to be a YAML format syntax error.

Comment: Also I would guess your `var.values` is a HCL2 map and your `local.values` is a YAML string, and the latter is a not a valid structure for an input argument to `compact`, so that is probably root cause here. Another good attempt at a first step forward would potentially be `compact([local.values, yamldecode(var.values)])`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 missed space before `vault_in_k8s`. Can you please confirm you have the same behavior after changing?

```
        - labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
             vault_in_k8s: true
```

to

```
        - labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              vault_in_k8s: true
```

---

```
locals{
  values  = <<EOF
injector:
  enabled: false
global:
  enabled: true
server:
  tolerations:
    - key: "taint_for_vault"
      operator: "Equal"
      value: true
      effect: "NoExecute"
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              vault_in_k8s: true
          topologyKey: "vault_in_k8s"
  EOF
}
```